# Expected variance of an a-postiori distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

> How can one show that the variance of an a-postiori distribution does not exceed the variance of an a-prori variance, i.e.
>
> $$E_X[\operatorname{Var}(\theta \mid X)] \leq \operatorname{Var}(\theta).$$

My idea was the following: $Var(\theta \mid X) = E[\theta^2 \mid X] - (E[\theta \mid X])^2$. Then we get:

$$E[Var(\theta \mid X)] = E[E[\theta^2 \mid X] - (E[\theta \mid X])^2] = E[E[\theta^2 \mid X]] - E[(E[\theta \mid X])^2]$$
$$= E[\theta^2]-E[(E[\theta \mid X])^2]$$

What should I do now? Jensen would give that above term is smaller than $E[\theta^2] - E[E[\theta^2 \mid X]]$ but this would be zero and therefore I don't get the desired result $Var(\theta) = E[\theta^2] - E[\theta]^2$. Where did I make the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with the RHS of the inequality. 
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(\theta) &= E[\theta^2] - E[\theta]^2 \\
&= E[ E[\theta^2 \mid X]] - (E[E[\theta \mid X]])^2 \quad \text{(Law of Total Expectation)} \\
&=  E[ \text{Var}[\theta \mid X] + (E[ \theta \mid X])^2] - (E[E[\theta \mid X]])^2 \\
&= E[\text{Var}[\theta \mid X]] + E[(E[\theta \mid X])^2] - (E[E[\theta \mid X]])^2 \\
&= E[\text{Var}[\theta \mid X]] + \underbrace{\text{Var}[E[\theta \mid X]]}_{\ge 0}
\end{align*}
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance.